# difference in writing condition with or and pipe in while loop based on variable existence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function to do `inorder` traversal for a `binary tree`. My function is as follows:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def inorderTraversal(root):
    """
    :type root: TreeNode
    :order: List[int]
    """

    stack = []
    order = []

    while stack or root:
        if root:
            stack.append(root)
            root = root.left

        else:
            current_node = stack.pop()
            order.append(current_node.val)
            root = current_node.right

    return order
```

Now, I am confused with this line

```
while stack or root: # this works fine
```

I tried to write it differently as follows:

```
while stack | root:
```

this caused the function to fail with the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'TreeNode'
```

Most of the times, I use `|` to compare conditions in `if statement` or dataframe `indexing` and it has been working fine.

What is the difference between `|` and `or`? Why does it fail in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a *bitwise* logical operator, and it can be overridden by custom classes. `or` is the canonical logical operator; it can't be overridden, it only works on `bool`s.

The line you're asking about takes advantage of implicit conversion to `bool` type of lists—and objects in general. If `stack` is empty, `bool(stack)` will return `False` (and `True`otherwise). Similarly, if `root` is bound to a `None` object, then `bool(root)` will return `False` (and `True`otherwise).

`while stack or root` is thus equivalent to `while len(stack) > 0 or root is not None`.

Answer (score 0):

`or` is a logical or, that you use in `if`-tests: it returns `True` if either of its operands is true-ish.

`|` is a bitwise or: it is used for manipulating bit-strings: for example 0b101 | 0b010 == 0b111.